# Converting raster symbology to vector shapefiles using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, symbology, classification

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have a satellite raster geoTIFF, the image shows a coastal region with water, rocks, grass.

To display these three features of interest, I've symbolised the raster via a classified style using 3 classes. The automatically created 3 classes respond quite well to the regions of water, rock and grass.

I therefore want to export this classified symbology as a vector shapefile (i.e., 3 shapefiles for the 3 classess. A shapefile for the pixel values that fall in the water values, another shapefile for the pixel values that fall into the rock values and a final shapefile for the pixel values that fall into the grass values).

Is this possible?

I know it is possible to create a classified raster using the supervised classification tools and create training datasets. However, I want to specifically convert the three classes from the automatically created from the classified symbology tab as shapefiles.

Comment: How many bands in your raster?

Comment: 1 band. It's panchromatic imagery (black and white)

Comment: Run reclassify on that raster. It will accept classes from symbology. Convert result raster to polygon.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there are better methodologies, but here is how I will approach the problem.

Firstly, make sure you have a "3 classes respond quite well". As felixIP said, number of bands, etc. would determine quality of classification.

Assuming you have good classification (i.e. no noises, etc), use 'Raster to Polygon' tool followed by split by attribute tool.

If you have noises, I would try filters first and then do step above. OR alternatively, generate a fishnet at same resolution as image --> zonal statistics --> split by attribute.

Comment: It is a single band black and white imagery. With this in mind, what are the steps for using the "Raster to Polygon" followed by the split by attribute tool.